# Insert another element with attribute value or scope model after directive element in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to create a directive that creates a `<dd>` element after each `<dt>` element created with ng-repeat directive. How do I set the content of the `<dd>` equal to directive attribute value, or ng-repeat scope model value?

```
<dl>
  <dt ng-repeat="item in items" insert-dd="{{ item.dd_vaue }}">{{ item.dt_value }}</dt>
</dl>

angular.directive('insertDd', function () {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var dd = angular.element('<dd> here is attrs.insertDd or scope.item.dd_value </dd>');
    dd.insertAfter(element);
    $compile(dd)(scope);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a `scope` on the directive to pass each `item`:

```
app.directive('insertDd', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            item: '=insertDd'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // ng-repeat always inserts the next item directly after the last one,
            // so this element will actually be before the <dt> we just added
            if (element.next().length) {
                element.next().after(element);
            }

            var dd = angular.element('<dd> here is {{item.dd_value}} or {{item.dt_value}} </dd>');

            element.after(dd);
            $compile(dd)(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sFEf5/2/

Comment: Thank you, that's what I want. But some strange things happening in my real project. The item.dt_value inside DT (the one that is in ngRepeat scope) disappears. Only the value from insertDd directive is printed. There's an empty space inside DT. And it gets back if I remove insertDd directive. I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Seems like insertDd directive changes the scope for ngRepeat directive. If I change the name of the model in the insertDd scope from 'item' to 'foo' then 'item' model disappears from ngRepeat scope. Why?